# Which http client to use in C# for get, post, and downloading files with progress tracking?

Tags: c#, http

My goal is:

- Access the website in a session.
- Pass login info using `HtmlAgilityPack`.
- From that session access multiple files (in no specific order but it doesn't matter).
- Download these files while keeping track of the download progress.
- Being able to get the file name before downloading (I found out that this is possible using `content-disposition` in the headers).

---

- I tried HttpClient and RestSharp but both don't allow tracking download progress or accessing file name before downloading.
- I tried WebClient which solves both previous issues but doesn't allow get or post the typical way which is mandatory here as well.

---

What I expect is to be able to parse a website after login and scan the html file for files to download (I know how to do this part and it is already solved) and while scanning to retrieve the files' names in something like future objects (I suppose this will be solved using async tasks which if requested immediately can be awaited, else can be called in background) and then when a file is requested, the file shall be downloaded while showing progress.

Comment: Hi Anton. "Recommend me a..." type questions are off topic for SO, I'm afraid, as they tend to attract opinion based rather than fact based answers as well as spam. This question will probably end up closed but feel free to pick your poison in terms of which http client to use, and ask for help where you run into trouble with it

Comment: `WebRequest`, `HttpClient` and `WebClient` can all be used to perform that task. `WebClient` being only partially useful. Parsing an `Html` file has nothing to do with any of them. *Session* is a server-side notion. A dynamic `Html` page can only be downloaded with some success with a `Lazy<HttpClient>`. No guarantees. -- Your question is probably off-topic, because it's asking to  *suggest* some kind of do-all tool and possibly too broad even if it wasn't.

Comment: My question wasn't for an opinion but to figure out which one to use when none can do the whole job, by session I meant keep the client active so it doesn't require log in again each time, something like the requests session in python. I expected at least a suggestion for which client to use (even if not listed in the post since none of them do what I need) or a similar solution or guide, something I don't know or I'm missing. @CaiusJard

Comment: Why do you think `HttpClient` will prevent you from tracking download progress?  You get a stream from the response and it's up to you to buffer that at some chunk of your choice (say into a `byte[1024]` array) and for each iteration of obtaining a chunk you obtain your progress.

Comment: Session Cookies can be stored/reloaded with `WebRequest`/`WebResponse`, `HttpClient` and also a custom `WebClient`. See: [CookieContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecontainer). This will allow to maintain an active session after a successful login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, I spend hours searching for a solution and I figure it out the moment I post the question here.

It turned out `HttpClient` is enough as multiple users mentioned, I just had to dig deeper and not stop reading when the SO answer said "not possible" which they meant not supported for specific files but possible overall. Anyway here is what I needed:

```
var processMsgHander = new ProgressMessageHandler(new HttpClientHandler());
processMsgHander.HttpSendProgress += (sender, e) =>
    {
        //add your codes base on e.BytesTransferred and e.ProgressPercentage
    };

processMsgHander.HttpReceiveProgress += (sender, e) =>
    {
        e.BytesTransferred.Dump();
        //add your codes base on e.BytesTransferred and e.ProgressPercentage
    };

var client = new HttpClient(processMsgHander);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mypage.com/");

var login = await client.GetAsync("http://mypage.com/login");

var text = await login.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);

var hiddenInput = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form//input[@type=\"hidden\"]");

var loginData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var x in hiddenInput)
{
    loginData[x.Attributes.First(t => t.Name == "name").Value] = x.Attributes.First(t => t.Name == "value").Value;
}

loginData["username"] = "MyUsername";
loginData["password"] = "MyPasswordShouldntBeHere";

var lginData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(loginData.ToArray());
var response = await client.PostAsync(login.RequestMessage.RequestUri, lginData);

var tF = DateTime.Now;

var file = await client.GetAsync("http://mypage.com/file");

var headers = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, "http://mypage.com/file"));

var tE = DateTime.Now;

file.Content.Headers.ElementAt(1).Dump(); // if only this is called then the file is downloaded
headers.Content.Headers.ElementAt(1).Dump(); // if only this is called then the file is not downloaded
// in my use case either the first line of the second will be called at one case
// (accordingly the var file and var headers won't both be called)

(tE - tF).Dump();
```